# Delete a DOM node using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I need to delete the 2 fields inserted when I click the remove link
I can only delete one.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var max_fields      = 25; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div class="col-md-6"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="mytext[]"/></div>'); //add input box
            $(wrapper).append('<div class="col-md-6"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="mytext2[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>');

        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })

});
```

Comment: why you just dont remove the div's with form-control class? or give them a special class? ("div.form-cntrol").remove();

Comment: yeah true the class is of the form-control not div, my mistake. you can add another class to the div. like '<div class="col-md-6 myclass" and then remove it. is this going to work?

Comment: nothing changed. it can only remove one field. i think its because of the parent ? im have no experience in javascript

Comment: Have you tried something like this?     $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $("div.myclass").remove(); x--;
    })

Comment: anyway it works thanks bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This May help you.......

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var max_fields      = 25; //maximum input boxes allowed
var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

var x = 1; //initlal text box count
$(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
        x++; //text box increment
        $(wrapper).append('<div class="col-md-6 div-'+x+'"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="mytext[]"/></div>'); //add input box
        $(wrapper).append('<div class="col-md-6 div-'+x+'"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="mytext2[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field" div-id="'+x+'">Remove</a></div>');

    }
});

$(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".div-"+$(this).attr("div-id")).remove(); 
    x--;
})

});
```